# How to rename sql column name in query result

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

I have a function where I build an array based on a mysqli query:

```
if ($type == 'item') {

    $the_query = "SELECT ID, SKU from store_items WHERE Qty > 0";

} else if ($type == 'brim') {

    $the_query = "SELECT ID, BrimID from store_item_brims";

} else if ($type == 'condition') {

    $the_query = "SELECT ID, CondDesc from store_item_conditions";

} else if ($type == 'grade') {

    $the_query = "SELECT ID, GradeDesc from store_item_grades";

}

$query = $db->query($the_query);

    if ($query->num_rows > 0) { 

        $results = array();

        while ($returned = $query->fetch_assoc()) {

            array_push($results, $returned);

        }
    }

    return $results;
```

For example, if `$type` was `item`, I would have an array like:

```
$array['ID'] // Some ID
$array['SKU'] // The SKU
```

And if `$type` was `brim`, I would have:

```
$array['ID'] // Some ID
$array['BrimID] // A brim ID
```

What I am trying to do is modify the query so that no matter what, the resulting array would have the same keys, namely:

```
$array['ID']
$array['Value']
```

So, no matter what the `$type` was, the array always has the keys of `ID` and `Value`.

How can I modify these queries to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use an alias (preferably one that makes sense, not `whatever` like I use):

```
if ($type == 'item') {    
    $the_query = "SELECT ID, SKU as whatever from store_items WHERE Qty > 0";    
} else if ($type == 'brim') {    
    $the_query = "SELECT ID, BrimID as whatever from store_item_brims";    
} else if ($type == 'condition') {    
    $the_query = "SELECT ID, CondDesc as whatever from store_item_conditions";    
} else if ($type == 'grade') {    
    $the_query = "SELECT ID, GradeDesc as whatever from store_item_grades";    
}
```

And the PHP:

```
$array['ID']
$array['whatever']
```